# Vaadin 14 Grid + Dialog: How to refresh grid after closing dialog?

Tags: java, dialog, grid, vaadin

I using Vaadin 14.
I have a Grid to show users. Also, I have a Button to create and save new users.
My MainGrid looks like here:

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final AddUserDialog addUserDialog;
    private Grid<UserDto> grid;

    public MainView(UserService userService,
                    AddUserDialog addUserDialog) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.addUserDialog = addUserDialog;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void renderComponents() {
        renderAddUserButton();
        renderUserGrid();
    }

    private void renderAddUserButton() {
        Button addUserButton = new Button("Добавить", VaadinIcon.PLUS.create());
        addUserButton.addClickListener(event -> addUserDialog.open());
        add(addUserButton);
    }
    private void renderUserGrid() {
        grid = new Grid<>(UserDto.class);
        //grid init here
        add(grid);
    }
}
```

And Dialog looks like here:

```
public class AddUserDialog extends Dialog {
    private final UserService userService;

    public AddUserDialog(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //init form here
    }
    private void save(Binder<UserDto> binder) {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        try {
            binder.writeBean(userDto);
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        userService.save(userDto);
        this.close();
    }
}
```

Please, advice, how to refresh grid after closing dialog?

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this, it's best to keep all the logic in the main view. If both your main view and the dialog both update data independently, it's very easy to end up in a situation where your data is inconsistent.

My suggestion is that you change the dialog to fire a saved-event when a user is saved and that you listen for that event in the main view and update it accordingly. This way, you only maintain the view state in one place.

```java
public class AddUserDialog extends Dialog {

    private void save(Binder<UserDto> binder) {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        try {
            binder.writeBean(userDto);
            fireEvent(new SaveEvent(this, userDto));
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static abstract class UserDialogEvent extends ComponentEvent<AddUserDialog> {
        private UserDto userDto;

        protected UserDialogEvent(AddUserDialog source, UserDto userDto) {
            super(source, false);
            this.userDto = userDto;
        }

        public UserDto getUserDto() {
            return userDto;
        }
    }

    public static class SaveEvent extends UserDialogEvent {
        public SaveEvent(AddUserDialog source, UserDto userDto) {
            super(source, userDto);
        }
    }

    public <T extends ComponentEvent<?>> Registration addListener(Class<T> eventType,
                                                                  ComponentEventListener<T> listener) {
        return getEventBus().addListener(eventType, listener);
    }
}
```

(You can get rid of the abstract event class if you don't see a need for additional events like cancel, etc)

Then, in `MainView`, listen for the event and update the state accordingly.

```java
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final AddUserDialog addUserDialog;
    private Grid<UserDto> grid;

    public MainView(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        addUserDialog = new AddUserDialog();
        addUserDialog.addListener(AddUserDialog.SaveEvent.class, this::saveUser);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void renderComponents() {
        renderAddUserButton();
        renderUserGrid();
    }

    private void renderAddUserButton() {
        Button addUserButton = new Button("Добавить", VaadinIcon.PLUS.create());
        addUserButton.addClickListener(event -> addUserDialog.open());
        add(addUserButton);
    }
    private void renderUserGrid() {
        grid = new Grid<>(UserDto.class);
        //grid init here
        add(grid);
    }

    private void saveUser(AddUserDialog.SaveEvent saveEvent) {
        userService.save(saveEvent.getUserDto());
        addUserDialog.close();
        refreshGrid();

        addUserDialog.addDialogCloseActionListener()
    }

    private void refreshGrid() {
        // refresh grid
    }
}
```